# How to include "File upload" field in the webform composite element?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have created a custom composite element, I want to include "File upload" field...The field is visible to the user and the file is uploaded. But it is nowhere saved.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the destination folder. This webform [FAQ](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-frequently-asked-questions/how-to-enable-the-public-file-system-for) might help you.

Edit: Webform Composite Elements do not support File elements yet. Reference on drupal [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-elements)

Follow these issues (active as of 6/20/2017) to find release updates-
https://www.drupal.org/node/2883734
, https://www.drupal.org/node/2884624

Comment: I have tried that, it didn't work. I have created a custom composite element $elements['transcripts'] = [ 
           '#type' => 'file',
           '#title' => t('transcripts'),
           '#multiple' => TRUE,
 ]; This is my code for the file upload.

Comment: Composite Elements doesn't support file elements.

Comment: @SAY True! doesn't support #multiple too.